# clear or delete the old slug of a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug

I have an old website that used a custom post type named `services`.

Now i am building the new site and i would like to delete the custom post type `services`, so I moved all the posts from the `services` CPT into simple pages.

I added these pages like as child pages of a parent page named "services", so I can use the same permalink as the old website.

```
site.com/services/name-of-service
```

Now I have a problem with the slug, I think there is a bug with the old slug.

In fact if navigate to `site.com/services/name-of-service` I get a 404 error, but if i move this page outside the parent "services" page this works well.

**How can I clear or delete the old slug?**

I have already updated the permalinks and cleared the cache, what else can I try ?

Comment: what is your permalink structure?

Comment: i would like to take the same permalinks structure.

so the old one with the cpt was: site.com/services/name-of-service


now i would like to keep the same, but without the cpt, but like a child of the parent service.


the setting in the permalink is: custom structure with this value "/%category%/%postname%/"

Comment: is your CPT enable in with the name `services` ? if its enable then you have to change the custom post type name to other because wordpress use unique URL structure if  CPT name matches with page then you will have `404` error.

Comment: thanks, i think that i found the problem. i have a plugin that write this custom post type still active. thanks anyway